# Percentage question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A family consumes Rice, Daal and Wheat. The ratio of its expenditure
>   is 12 : 17 : 3. If the price of those commodities increases by 20%,
>   30% and 50% respectively. By how much expenditure will be increased of
>   that family.

Daal=Pulses

Can anyone give any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

$12/32 + 17/32 + 3/32 = 1$

$(12*1.2)/32 + (17*1.3)/32 + (3*1.5)/32 = x$

$(x - 1)*100 = $ percentage increase in expenditure